# Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act="android.search.action.GLOBAL_SEARCH" }

Tags: android, search, provider, assistant

I'm facing strange behavior with Google Assistance during execution of adb command that performs a search query on the device:

```
adb shell am start -a “android.search.action.GLOBAL_SEARCH” --es query \“football\”
```

Result is:

```
Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act="android.search.action.GLOBAL_SEARCH" ...
```

and no search item then.

[terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9tT9.png)

This error disappeared when on device "Developer Options" was turned off and then on.

And we have search provider registered in the Manifest like that:

```
<provider android:name="com.ourcompany.cordova.plugins.search.SearchProvider" android:authorities="com.ourcompany.cordova.plugins.search" android:exported="true">
    <path-permission android:pathPrefix="/search" android:readPermission="android.permission.GLOBAL_SEARCH"/>
</provider>
```

Android 8.0.0, API 26, NVidia Shield

Any ideas why this error might occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Remove quotation mark for '“android.search.action.GLOBAL_SEARCH”' and then try, as follows :

```
adb shell am start -a android.search.action.GLOBAL_SEARCH --es query football
```

Comment: Yes, it's correct answer, the root of the problem was - copy paste from Slack.